# How to get index value of search data in table view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview, searchbar

I am using a tableview controller with the searchbar.  I want to get all index positions of the array elements which are related to a search result of any string from a table.

For example: If I have an array containing the following: @"sau",@"jain",@"abc",@"sau",@"zyx" and I search for 'sau' then I want it to output index 0 and 3.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: It would be better to compare the search string to table_array elements.the index that you get is the value..

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"sau", @"jain", @"abc", @"sau", @"zyx" ];

NSString *searchString = @"sau";
NSIndexSet *result = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *string, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange searchStringRange = [string rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    return searchStringRange.length > 0;
}];
NSLog(@"Result indexes: %@", result);
```

Console output is `Result indexes: <NSIndexSet: 0x8a80c50>[number of indexes: 2 (in 2 ranges), indexes: (0 3)]`

Tune code within the block to match you search logic

**Edit**

Or to process objects on one by one basis

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"sau", @"jain", @"abc", @"sau", @"zyx" ];

NSString *searchString = @"sau";
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    BOOL searchCondition = [obj isEqualToString:searchString];
    if (!searchCondition) return;

    // You logic to process objects passing the search condition
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new in iPhone. I am getting result but I wanna result in one by one index position not in set because I have to passed this index value in another array.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable support. But I wanna little bit different. I have table view where 3 label are present and in this data is coming from 3 different array. And Now when I search in search bar by first label which is username then I wanna that in table all data show which are related to searching criteria. Means as I have already gave example that if @"sau" is found in 2 position then the corresponding related data from array is shown in table. Thanks for support . Please help.

Comment: Hello...I am starting to make an iPhone chat application where the users can do private chat.So can you gave any idea, or any running application, or any code to that. Thanks.